# MySQL join multiple tables and limit the output from "ON"

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join

when i write a MySQL query, there occur a problem. here is my query

```
SELECT 
    SUM(view_product_count_details.view_product_count) AS count_sum,
    product_details.product_name,
    product_details.product_url,
    product_details.product_price,
    product_image_details.product_image_name,
    main_category_details.main_category_url,
    sub_category_details.sub_category_url
FROM
    view_product_count_details
        JOIN
    product_details ON view_product_count_details.product_id_fk = product_details.product_id
        JOIN
    product_image_details ON product_image_details.product_id_fk = view_product_count_details.product_id_fk
        JOIN
    main_category_details ON product_details.product_main_cat_id = main_category_details.main_category_id
        JOIN
    sub_category_details ON product_details.product_sub_cat_id_fk = sub_category_details.sub_category_id
WHERE
    view_product_count_details.view_product_status = 'active'
GROUP BY view_product_count_details.product_id_fk
ORDER BY count_sum DESC
LIMIT 4
```

Here I have multiple images for one product.the images are in table "product_image_details". this query returns count as the number of images, where I need the count of product viewed by people which is stored in table "view_product_count_details". when I just pick the count, i got the count as it is. but when i join the table "product_image details", result become wrong. Is there any way to do it in single query?

Please help me... Thanks in advance.... :)

Comment: Can you post table schema

Comment: Is view_product_count having the count? or do you need to count number of rows view_product_count_details in the table and get the count?

Comment: Problem is probably that view_product_count will be counted once for each product_image_details for that product.

Comment: when i try to post the table schema, it shows error of size. and i'm new here so cant paste it as answer too. :(

Comment: I think the problem is exactly what  "Kickstart" said. it didnt make problem when i take the data without images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by having an inline query. I am not sure how this will perform when you have more data.

```
    SELECT table1.*,product_image_details.product_image_name FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            SUM(view_product_count_details.view_product_count) AS count_sum,
            product_details.product_id,
            product_details.product_name,
            product_details.product_url,
            product_details.product_price,
            main_category_details.main_category_url,
            sub_category_details.sub_category_url
        FROM
            view_product_count_details
                JOIN
            product_details ON view_product_count_details.product_id_fk = product_details.product_id
                JOIN
            product_image_details ON product_image_details.product_id_fk = view_product_count_details.product_id_fk
                JOIN
            main_category_details ON product_details.product_main_cat_id = main_category_details.main_category_id
                JOIN
            sub_category_details ON product_details.product_sub_cat_id_fk = sub_category_details.sub_category_id
        WHERE
            view_product_count_details.view_product_status = 'active'
        GROUP BY view_product_count_details.product_id_fk
        ORDER BY count_sum DESC
        LIMIT 4
    ) table1
        JOIN
    product_image_details ON product_image_details.product_id_fk = table1.product_id    
    LIMIT 4
```

Comment: Thank you nish for the quick reply. But it didnt work :(. it shows the error "[Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'view_product_count_details.product_id_fk' in 'on clause'"

Comment: the "view_product_count" having the count for each product.when i give this query the count is incremented according to the number of images. that is, if there is count 1 and 3 images, it will show the count as 3

Comment: Can you provide the schema diagram for your database? That will give better understanding.

Comment: You need to change the sub query to return view_product_count_details.product_id_fk, and then refer to it (using the name it is returned as, probably table1.product_id_fk) in the JOIN between the sub query and product_image_details.

Comment: @Kickstart Thank you :) I updated as per your comment.

Comment: @nish thank you for the update....now the error has gone..nut still it give the same output as i got before.... :(

Comment: a lot of thanks for all your support.... i made alil change on the query and i got what i want..... thanks a lot... i deleted the line "JOIN
            product_image_details ON product_image_details.product_id_fk = view_product_count_details.product_id_fk" in the sub query